# Why is Pyspark expecting type basestring when exporting a dataframe to csv or txt file?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am using Pyspark in the community version of Databricks, using Python 2.7 and Spark 2.2.1. I have a Pyspark dataframe "top100m":

```
In: type(movie_ratings_top100m)
Out: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
```

Which has 3 numeric type columns:

```
In: top100m.printSchema()
Out: root
 |-- userId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- itemId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- userPref: double (nullable = true)

In: top100m.show(6)
Out: 
+------+-------+--------+
|userId| itemId|userPref|
+------+-------+--------+
|   243|     10|     3.5|
|   243|     34|     3.5|
|   243|     47|     4.0|
|   243|    110|     4.0|
|   243|    150|     2.5|
|   243|    153|     2.0|
+------+-------+--------+
```

There are no strings in the dataframe. When attempting to output this file as either a csv or a txt file using either the following lines of code (based on Databricks documentation found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/advanced/filestore.html)):

```
dbutils.fs.put("/FileStore/mylocation/top100m.csv", top100m)
dbutils.fs.put("/FileStore/mylocation/top100m.txt", top100m)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: DataFrame[userId: bigint, itemId: bigint, userPref: double] has the wrong type - (<type 'basestring'>,) is expected.
```

I have a cursory understanding of the basestring supertype that existed in Python 2, and that it was abandoned in Python 3, which I don't think is relevant here, but I could be wrong. My ultimate goal with this is to be able to export my Pyspark dataframe from Databricks onto my local machine. My question is why Spark/Databricks would be expecting a basestring type in this case, and what I can do with my data to make it comply.

After reviewing the Databricks documentation including [forums](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6717/exporting-data-from-databricks.html), it seems that there isn't a very straightforward way of transferring data to my local machine (I'm not attached to an S3 bucket). The simplest seems to be the approach I've noted above, which is giving me errors. If there is a better way to accomplish this, that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the databricks [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/importing-data.html#load-data) csv files can be loaded into Spark from DBFS using `sqlContext`. Since that is the case, you can save data in a similar way (some information regarding saving RDDs is available [here](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html#access-dbfs-using-the-spark-api)). In other words, there is no need to use `dbutils` for saving, instead do:

```
top100m.write.format("csv").save("/FileStore/mylocation/top100m.csv")
```

Due to how Spark saves files `top100m.csv` will be a directory. Inside there will be one csv file for each partition of the dataframe. These are called `part-xxxxx` (where xxxxx is a number starting from 00000). It's possible to get a single part file by calling `coalesce(1)` on the dataframe before saving it. In this case, the csv file will be called `part-00000`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Shaido. It seems to be saving to the FileStore. I'm running into problems extracting it as a csv though. I'm following the instructions here: https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/advanced/filestore.html, more specifically, I'm using the url: https://community.cloud.databricks.com/files/mylocation/top100m.csv?o=<<myDatabricksCommunityID>>, but the file that is exported is an HTML file and when opened, it simply says, "HTTP ERROR: 500

Can't open /devtierprod1/<<myDatabricksCommunityID>>/FileStore/mylocation/top100m.csv because it is a directory"  Any ideas?

Comment: @Naim I'm quite sure it's due to how Spark saves files. top100m.csv will indeed become a directory, inside will be one file called `part-xxxxx` for each partition of the dataframe. It's possible to get a single file in the directory (part-00000) by calling `.coalesce(1)` on the dataframe before saving it. I added this information to the answer.